# locate partial file name mlocate

Tags: 13.10, locate

I want to find a file using `locate` command. I'm not much sure the file name. I have following files in 3-4 folder in my home directory.

```
PRVL_Securities_0200_H240401.html
PRVL_TermLeasehold_0000_H200401.html
PRVL_Trees_0000_Hxx0401.html
PRVL_TrustBeneficiaryRight_0000_H220401.html
PRVL_UnlistedSecurities_0101_H250527.html
PRVL_UnlistedSecurities_0102_H250527.html
PRVL_UnlistedSecurities_0200_H250527.html
PRVL_UnlistedSecurities_0300_H250527.html
PRVL_UnlistedSecurities_0400_H250527.html
PRVL_UnlistedSecurities_0500_H250527.html
PRVL_UnlistedSecurities_0600_H250527.html
```

I'm looking for a files containing word `"security"` or  `"securities"`. I want exact path of the file. How can I do that using locate comand?

Comment: @Rinzwind Yes, but depending on how many directories need to be traversed, `locate` may be a lot quicker, although in this case, "security" brings up a lot of false positives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Bash globbing patterns](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm). Hence,

```
locate *securit{y,ies}*
```

As stated in my comments above, you'll find there are many matches for "security" in non-user directories, so you may want to restrict to your home directory with

```
locate *securit{y,ies}*|grep "^$HOME"
```

Or if it's a specific subdirectory,

```
locate *securit{y,ies}*|grep "^$HOME/path/to/directory"
```

Or use `find`, as Rinzwind suggests. In this simple case, I don't think there's a strong advantage to using `find`, which is more powerful (but potentially slower) than `locate`.

```
find ~/path/to/directory -name '*security*' -or -name "*securities*"
```

(I'm not sure how to make find accept globbing patterns.)